# Retrieving device class guid or driver key

Tags: c#, winforms, wmi

I am trying to find the "**Device class guid**" or the "**Driver key**" for a particular graphic card device (value can be seen in device manager).

I've looked into [Win32_VideoController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Win32_DisplayConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (among a few others) but it doesn't look like you can get either of those values through those WMI classes.

Is there an alternative way, or a WMI class I am missing that I can use to obtain the above values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is where I found mine, you'll need to know the name of the video driver, on my machine it is Generic PnP Monitor.  Uses the Win32_PnPEntity of WMI, snip is VBS from WMI Code Creator.

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Name = 'Generic PnP Monitor'",,48) 
For Each objItem in colItems 
    Wscript.Echo "-----------------------------------"
    Wscript.Echo "Win32_PnPEntity instance"
    Wscript.Echo "-----------------------------------"
    Wscript.Echo "ClassGuid: " & objItem.ClassGuid
    Wscript.Echo "Name: " & objItem.Name
Next
```

Comment: Doesn't your query imply that I know what the class guid is ? That is the value I am trying to retrieve. Based on your query you are using the class guid in order to find an item to output its class guid value (obviously it will be the same).

Comment: fixed, search by name of the driver.   or any identifier you prefer, I see about a 30-40 fields in WMI code creator.